# C# or C++ frozen pane that shrinks desktop

Tags: c#, visual-c++, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Microsoft One Note 2010 implement a window that is docked to the desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850038/how-does-microsoft-one-note-2010-implement-a-window-that-is-docked-to-the-deskto)

I was wondering how one would go about making a program (in C# or C++) that would have a frozen pane and shrink the active area of the rest of the screen. A good example of this is the Facebook client chat program in full screen mode because it is always on top as well as shrinks the area of the screen that is active, including shrinking the desktop. What I'm trying to achieve is the green bar in the picture below that can never go away:

(note please ignore the red circle in the photo below, the only picture I could find of what I'm trying to do was from a meme about how on all military sites they have a suicide hotline because the systems are all so slow, they make you want to kill yourself)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented on MSDN as an "AppBar": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's a regular Win32 window anchored to one edge of the screen and also reduces the area for other windows to maximize into.

Comment: Searching the AppBar you talked about, I also found a C# variant here for anyone else reading this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6741/AppBar-using-C